# JPA excpected behaviour when loading an entity with a non exsistend child entity

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys, entity

What's the proper JPA behaviour when loading an Entity like the following:

```
puiblic class Employee  
{
  @ManyToOne  
  @JoinColumns("ID_COMPANY")  
  private Company company;
  ...
}
```

When I try do load an Employee and the referred Company entity does not exsist ?

I mean,
In my Application the company entity is null in such a case, is this the expected behaviour or should it throw a EntityNotFound exception ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not specified @ManyToOne(**optional** = false) or  @JoinColumn(**nullable** = false) an Employee can exist without a Company, so when you load the Employee the company field is simply null.

If a Employee can't exist without being assigned to a company, it should be enforced using the two annotation properties above. @JoinColumn(nullable = false) is only used if you create you tables from JPA meta data, the optional = false, is a hit to JPA that it can actually throw an exception during validation before talking to the database.

You should always be as strict as possible when defining the data model, anything that can't logically exist without something else, should have nullable=false (also for basic columns), so you get NOT NULL enforced at the database level. It is much nicer to have your code fail with a Constraint Violation Exception, than discover a NullPointerException later when you have loaded the data call some method.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer and your time, one more think: ID_COMPANY is not null, but it simply refers to a non exsisting COMPANY, does your answers holds true in this situation ? Also when is EntityNotFouldException thrown by JPA in such a situation ?